# Text margins in beamer vs adjustwidth (changepage.sty)

Tags: beamer, margins, layout, changepage

Some (not all) slides in my beamer presentation need to have a wider text block. I know that I can use a `columns` env with a single `column` of arbitrary width, but that's a bit verbose. 
When I  discovered [`changepage.sty`](https://mirrors.chevalier.io/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/changepage/changepage.pdf) it first seemed that the `\adjustwidth` env does precisely what I want.

However, I can't get beamer's `block` environment to play nice with `\adjustwidth` (cf part 5 in MWE below). 
What am I doing wrong ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{orchid}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow]

\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

  \centerline{1}
  \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} % 1: used for reference

  \bigskip
  \bigskip
  \centerline{2}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{0pt}{0pt}
      \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} % looks fine
  \end{adjustwidth}

  \bigskip
  \bigskip
  \centerline{3}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
    \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} % looks fine too (i.e. full \paperwidth) 
  \end{adjustwidth}

  \bigskip
  \bigskip
  \centerline{4}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
    \rule{128mm}{1pt} % still fine (paper is 128mm wide by default)
  \end{adjustwidth}

  \bigskip
  \bigskip

  \centerline{5}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
    \begin{block}{}
      \rule{128mm}{1pt} % goes beyond the edge of the page

      \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} % does not have the intented length
    \end{block}
  \end{adjustwidth}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own `adjustwidth` environment (based on `columns` environment):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{orchid}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow]

%\usepackage{changepage}

\newenvironment{adjustwidth}[2]{
  \begin{columns}
    \column{\dimexpr\linewidth-#1-#2}
}{\end{columns}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

  \centerline{1}
  \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} % 1: used for reference

  \bigskip
  \bigskip
  \centerline{2}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{0pt}{0pt}
      \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} % looks fine
  \end{adjustwidth}

  \bigskip
  \bigskip
  \centerline{3}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
    \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} % looks fine too (i.e. full \paperwidth) 
  \end{adjustwidth}

  \bigskip
  \bigskip
  \centerline{4}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
    \rule{128mm}{1pt} % still fine (paper is 128mm wide by default)
  \end{adjustwidth}

  \bigskip
  \bigskip

  \centerline{5}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
    \begin{block}{}
      \rule{128mm}{1pt} % goes beyond the edge of the page

      \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} % does not have the intented length
    \end{block}
  \end{adjustwidth}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```